# How can I fix Inaccurate bounding boxes on foreground mask?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to build a squat detector in openCV for python for a University project and have been testing a variety of different methods, such as people object detection, barbell tracking and motion detection.

One method I am currently testing at the moment is using openCV's `cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()` function to create a foreground mask of each video frame. Using this mask, I then find the contours which I can use to then draw a bounding box around the (hopefully) detected object (person) in the foreground.

However, looking at some select frames, I can see that sometimes when there looks like a clear object (person) in the foreground mask, the resulting bounding box is either missing or not accurate at all. Please see below for my code and two frame outputs:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/content/drive/MyDrive/openCV/GW_BS2.mp4')
minArea = 5000 # Min size in pixels for a region of an image to be considered actual motion
frameNum = 0

backSub = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(150, 16, False)
while True:
  # Get current frame
  frame = cap.read()[1]

  # If frame is None, end the loop as video end has been reached
  if frame is None:
    break

  # Resize the frame, convert to gray and blur ready for back sub
  frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500) # Resize as no point processing large images
  fgMask = backSub.apply(frame)

  # Find contours to find outlines of white regions of threshold
  cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(fgMask.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

  for cnt in cnts:
      (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
      if cv2.contourArea(cnt) < minArea:
        continue
      cv2.drawContours(frame, cnt, -1, (255, 0, 0), 3)
      cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
      cv2.putText(frame, str(cv2.contourArea(cnt)), (x+5, y+15),
              cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (0,0,0))

# Add frame number to top left of frame
  cv2.rectangle(frame, (10, 2), (100, 20), (255, 255, 255), -1)
  cv2.putText(frame, str(frameNum), (15, 15),
          cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,0))

  if frameNum%10 == 0:
    # Show every 10 frames
    cv2_imshow(frame)
    cv2_imshow(fgMask)

  frameNum += 1
```

(I am using Google colab, so please excuse the weird cv2_imshow() function.)

See below for a couple of foreground masks and their respective output frame:

[image: examples]

As you can see, there is seemingly quite a good foreground mask here, but looking at the top output frame, there is no contours, nor bounding box. Whereas the bottom example, there is a slightly noisier foreground mask with some erroneous boxes and contours.

Any help on how to get the box to cover the whole person will be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks,

Harry

Comment: don't do canny. Get the bounding box directly on the white pixels on the foreground mask (eventually apply erosion on the foreground mask to remove some noise)

Comment: Hi @Miki, I've been playing around with erosion, closing and opening morphological methods after some research and it has definitely improved the accuracy, thanks! Fine tuning the MOG2 parameters (reducing the no. frames learning from to 75) has also improved the results. Thanks!